# How to add css file to Squarespace developer mode

Tags: css, squarespace

I added `index.css` inside styles, and included it in `template.conf`:

```
{
  "name": "Wright",
  "author": "Squarespace, Inc.",
  "layouts": {
    "default": {
      "name": "Default",
      "regions": [
        "site"
      ]
    }
  },
  "stylesheets": [
    "index.css"
  ],
  etc...
}
```

I see from the documentation that stylesheets will be compiled into `site.css`:

```
stylesheets

List of your stylesheet. Stylesheets will be compiled into site.css following the ordering here.

NOTE: If you add a file named reset.css to the /styles/ folder it will automatically get added to the top of the site.css file. It should not be listed in the "stylesheets" variable in template.conf.
```

Where is this `site.css` file? How is it called from `site.region`?

Currently, I'm unable to load the custom css file this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `site.css` is the resulting output of the compilation of all Squarespace's default styles as well as any styles you add via `stylesheets: [ ... ]` as you have in your question.

It is automatically created for you whenever your (or Squarespace's) stylesheets change. You do not have direct write access to it and it will not be seen within your template.

Therefore, if you have in fact done as you stated in your question (adding the file in `/styles` and adding it to your `template.conf` file), and if you have then updated your template via Git (note that SFTP is buggy and may not update your files), your CSS will be included in site.css thereafter when users load the site.

To answer your last question, the site.css file is not loaded directly via any region file. That is to say, if you search for it within the code, you will not find it. Rather, it is loaded as part of `{squarespace-headers}`, which you will find within your template files, either within a `.region` file or a `.block` file.